# django.contrib.auth.authenticate fails

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

`authenticate()` is not working for me. I have looked at the numerous other related questions but I haven't been able to get things working.

The request comes in as: `b'{"email":"test@test.test","password":"test"}'`

```
class LoginView(views.APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
        email = data.get('email', None)
        password = data.get('password', None)

        account = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
```

but `authenticate()` returns as  `None`. The account definitely exists.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Are you sure its the correct password?.. how did you set that in the first place

Comment: For the default user model, `authenticate()` expects `username`, not `email`. If you have a custom user model, you should include it in your question.